# difference between intent(inout) and pointer dummy arguments

Tags: fortran, fortran90

What is the practical difference in having

```
subroutine fillName(person)
   type(PersonType), intent(inout) :: person

   person%name = "Name"
end subroutine
```

or the following

```
subroutine fillName(person)
   type(PersonType), pointer :: person

   person%name = "Name"
end subroutine
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pointer` has specific argument requirements that the bare description does not have. Basically the dummy argument `person` must be associated with a pointer target. It could be through an allocation or simple pointer assignment (`=>`). An important thing to note is that any changes to the pointer association of the dummy argument `person` during the execution of the subroutine will be reflected in the actual argument passed. The bare description will pass the actual argument by reference, but not pointer association.

Answer (score 1):

If I assume the keyword is **practical**,
then the practical difference in the example you give would be **readability**, since they both work but `intent(inout)` is more explicit.

The technical difference is that the pointer may be null or undetermined, whereas with `intent(inout)` the variable have to be allocated. A pointer can also be associated or nullified in the subroutine but a dummy argument with `intent(inout)` cannot.

If you don't specify neither `pointer` or `intent(inout)` and you pass a pointer in argument then it have to be associated.